# Making member package protected using wildcards

Tags: scala

I have the following situation:

```scala
package com.my.organisation.common.gateway

object Singleton {
  val entrypoint = Entrypoint()
}
```

I would like to make `entrypoint` available to classes within `com.my.organisation.common.gateway` but also within `com.my.organisation.other.gateway` and also other future `com.my.organisation.*.gateway` packages.

Is there a way of doing this in Scala? `protected val[com.my.organisation.*.gateway]` does not compile, but that's the behaviour that I am aiming for.

Comment: There are no wildcards with access control in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
package com.my.organisation.common.gateway

object Singleton {
  private[organisation] val entrypoint = Entrypoint()
}
```

see also: https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package/

Comment: I don't want every class in `organisation` to be able to access `entrypoint`, only those that match `organisation.[anything].gateway`

Comment: Then, how about adjust package struct? change `organisation.[anything].gateway` to `organisation.gateway.[anything]`, and then use `private [gateway] val anything = ???`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a [package object](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/package-objects.html) declared in the most common path of the 2 packages. Then this can be shared to all sub-packages, because package objects acts as convenient containers shared across an entire package.

Assuming the code for `Entrypoint` is defined somewhere in the earlier packages.

```
// in file com/my/organisation/package.scala
package com.my
package object organisation {
   val entrypoint: Entrypoint = Entrypoint()
}
```

Then you can import it with `import com.my.organisation._`  wherever you need it.